# Define a variable with a subvariable (or with a property)

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, declaration

The target is to have a variable with a Unit property, which could be accessed by e.g.:

```
Params MyParams;    

MyParams.Diae = 100.0;
MyParams.Diae.Unit = "kg";
```

Ideally, the variable Diae is a member of Class Params and should Inherit the Unit property from a class IParameter:

```
internal class IParameter
{
    string unit;
    internal string Unit { get; set; }

    internal IParameter()
    {
        unit = "";
    }

}
```

How to declare Diae variable? Here is a snippet of a quasi-code of the declaration expected:

```
namespace SomeCode
{
    internal class Params
    {
        double diae;

        internal class Diae:IParameter
        {
            get { return diae; }
            set { diae = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, what do you want exactly? A class that contains a `double Value` and a `string Unit`? What is your final goal?

Comment: That would add complexity (you would need two classes) without any discernible benefit.

Comment: The variable declared as object String has the possibility to have a value. And it is possible to access the length of the variable by appending .Length the variable. I targeted for something similar. Accessing the value of the variable happens more often than its unit, therefore the desired implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly what you want -- you can't add extra properties to an existing type like `double`, so you'll have to make `Diae` return a separate class.  Something like this:

```
internal class ParamWithUnit
{
  public string Unit { get; set; }
  public double Value { get; set; }
}

internal class Params
{
  private ParamWithUnit diae = new ParamWithUnit();

  public ParamWithUnit Diae 
  {
    get { return this.diae; }
  }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
Params MyParams = new Params();    

MyParams.Diae.Value = 100.0;
MyParams.Diae.Unit = "kg";
```

Answer (score -1):

You won't [want to] be able to assign a double to `Diae` while still allowing it to have a property `Unit`.  (You could hack around this through implicit conversions or something like that, but I would discourage you from doing so.)

The best option would be to create a class such as `Measurement` that will have both a `Value` and a `Unit` property:

```
public class Measurement
{
    public double Value {get;set;}
    public string Unit {get;set;}
}
```

Then `Diae` can be of that type:

```
internal class Params
{
    public Measurement Diae {get;private set}
    public Params()
    {
        Diae = new Measurement();
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Params MyParams = new Params();    

MyParams.Diae.Value = 100.0;
MyParams.Diae.Unit = "kg";
```

Comment: What about making an extension to the intrinsic Double object. Would this be "clean"?

Comment: @Jansk83 As I said in my answer, that's possible, but undesirable.